# Prove that $|G| = |Z(G)| + \sum_{i' \in I'}|G:C_G(x_{i'})|$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Define $\rho: G \to Sym(G)$ by $\rho(g) = c_g,$ where $c_g:G \to G (y  \mapsto gyg^{-1}). $ Denote $(\rho(g))(x) =g(x)$

For $x\in G,$ define $G_x: = \{g\in G| g(x) = x\}$ and  $Gx := \{g(x) | g \in G\}$.

Also, $\exists \{x_i | i \in I\} \subseteq G$ such that $G := \bigsqcup_ {i\in I}Gx_i.$

I have already proven the following lemmas:

1.) $|Gx| =|G:G_x|$ and $|G| = \sum_{i \in I} |G:G_{x_i}|$

2.) $c_g$ is an isomorphism and $\rho$ is a homomorphism.

3.) $G_x = C_G(x)$

4.) $C_G(x) = G \Longleftrightarrow x \in Z(G).$

How do I USE THE 4 LEMMAS to prove that $|G| = |Z(G)| + \sum_{i' \in I'}|G:C_G(x_{i'})|,$ where $I' = \{i \in I:  |G: C_G(x_{i'})| \geq 2\}? $

I think it suffices to prove $G = Z(G) \sqcup $ $\bigsqcup_{i'\in I'}Gx_{i'}.$ Could anyone advise please? Thank you.

Comment: You write $G:=\sqcup_{i\in I}Gx_i$, but $G$ is already defined. Rather, did you intend to note that the equality indeed holds, or to define $I$ and the $x_i$'s such that it does?

Comment: Pardon my phrasing. Yes, I intend to note that the equality indeed holds. See my edition. Thank you.

Comment: That was partially intended as a hint: $\bigsqcup_{i\in I}Gx_i = (\bigsqcup_{i\in I\setminus I^\prime}Gx_i)\sqcup(\bigsqcup_{i^\prime\in I^\prime}Gx_{i^\prime})$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question and has been addressed in the comments. I am outlining an answer here so the question does not remain forever listed as unanswered.

We know that the orbits of this action form a partition of $G$. 
So we can write $G = \coprod_{i \in I} Gx_{i}$

We can group together the orbits that have size $1$ and those that do not have size $1$, as the OP has tried and is suggested in the comments. 
$$G = \coprod_{i \in I \setminus I^{\prime}} Gx_{i} \; \amalg \; \coprod_{i^{\prime} \in I^{\prime}} Gx_{i^{\prime}}$$

Combining what the OP calls Lemma 1, 3 and 4, we see that an element $x$ is in the centre of $G$ if and only if the orbit $Gx$ has size $1$. Hence we see that we have 
$$G = Z(G) \amalg \coprod_{i^{\prime} \in I^{\prime}} Gx_{i^{\prime}}$$.

As all the sets are disjoint (since the orbits are disjoint), the desired result about the order follows.